# Listing elements from set-builder notation, and vice versa

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, pattern-recognition

I have trouble translating from a set-builder notation to a "dotted set"
$$\{\ldots,v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots\}$$
and vice-versa.

*Set-builder to dotted set:*

$$\begin{align*}
A &= \{5a+ 2b : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\  
B &= \{6a + 2b : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align*}$$

Here, my problem is that I don't know how to list every element of the set. I get confused because there are 2 variables.

*Dotted set to set-builder:*

$$\begin{align*}
C &= \{0,4,16,36,64,100, \ldots\} \\
D &= \{0,1,4,9,16,25, \ldots\}  \\
E &= \{3,6,11,18,27,38, \ldots\}
\end{align*}$$

Here, my problem is that I know that this set follows a certain **pattern**, but I don't know how to **extract** this pattern, and express it in set builder notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the two set-builder $\to$ dotted set questions you mentioned, you should use Bezout's identity ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)), which essentially says that
$$\{ma+nb:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{dc:c\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
where $d=\gcd(m,n)$. Thus, concrete knowledge about this particular situation is necessary to simplify the representation of the set.

For the reverse, it is **impossible** in principle because an infinite number of patterns will match a given finite set of data, but you are expected to make a "reasonable" guess as to what the question-writer was thinking of. For example, the probable intention was
$$D=\{n^2:n\in\mathbb{Z},n\geq 0\}$$
Any polynomial-type patterns are findable via the calculus of finite differences.

Answer (score 0):

For your *Set-builder to dotted set* problem, you just need (1) a reliable pattern to list all the integers (i.e. 0, 1, -1, 2, -2...), then you a reliable way to mix two of those reliable lists, which we can copy from the standard trick to list all the rational numbers (i.e. diagonalise)

( 0, 0) **( 1, 0)** (-1, 0) **( 2, 0)** (-2, 0)...

**( 0, 1)** ( 1, 1) **(-1, 1)** ( 2, 1)...

( 0,-1) **( 1,-1)** (-1,-1)...

**( 0, 2)** ( 1, 2)...

from which we can take the top left (0,0), then the diagonal from top second **(1,0)** to the **(0, 1)** and so on:

(0,0), **(1,0)**, **(0, 1)**, (-1, 0), ( 1, 1), ( 0,-1), **( 2, 0)**, **(-1, 1)**, **( 1,-1)**, **( 0, 2)**...

now apply $A$'s rule

5(0) + 2(0)

5(1) + 2(0)

5(0) + 2(1)

5(-1) + 2(0)

5(1) + 2(1)

...

---

For your *Dotted set to set-builder* problem, I can't really help. I usually figure them out my looking at them, or if that doesn't work, thinking about the difference between each item in the list. Here's the answer to those problems.

$$\begin{align*}
C &= \{ (2i)^2 : i \in Z \text{ and } i \ge 0  \} \\
D &= \{ i^2 : i \in Z \text{ and } i \ge 0 \} \\
E &= \{ 2 + i^2 : i \in Z \text{ and } i \ge 1 \}
\end{align*}$$